# Validation Drop-List crashes with more than 21 values

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

This is my first question. I'm trying to make a very simple macro on VBA for Excel.

I want the code to open a database in Access, read the Table Names from the database, save them in a dynamic string, and then use that value to create a drop-list on a specific cell on the sheet.

The code is part of a group of macros, so when finishing the above, it creates a button next to the dropdown cell, and launches a message to warn the user that, after selecting the desired table, he/she should press a button to launch the next macro (which I don't report because that one works fine).

Here's the code I've been using so far:

```
Sub consultaAccess_v4_1()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim datos As Object
    Dim consultaSQL As String
    Dim conexion As String
    Dim cont As Long
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim NombresTablas() As String
    
    Sheets("Indice").Select
    Range("C10").Clear
    
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\0205406\Desktop\Base_Datos(EN PROCESO).accdb"
        
    cn.Open conexion

    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
    i = 0
    a = 0
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If rs.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value Like "MSys*" Then
            rs.MoveNext
        ElseIf rs.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value Like "~*" Then
            rs.MoveNext
        Else
            ReDim Preserve NombresTablas(i)
            NombresTablas(i) = rs.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value
            rs.MoveNext
            i = i + 1
            a = a + 1
            If a = 21 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop

    With Worksheets("Indice").Range("C10").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(NombresTablas, ",")
    End With
    
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Dim t As Range
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, 5), Cells(10, 5))
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    With btn
        .OnAction = "consultaAccess_v4_2"
        .Caption = "Continuar"
        .Name = "Continuar"
    End With
        
    Range("C10").Select
    MsgBox "Seleccione una tabla del desplegable y pulsa 'Continuar'"
End Sub
```

The macro works fine, and it works as I want it to work, but I have a problem: if I launch it, and close excel saving changes, when I open it again, I get the following message:

[image]

For non-Spanish speakers, the error says that there is a bug in the content of the book, and that if I trust the content, excel can try to recover as much of it as possible. After clicking on "Yes" and opening the VBA, this is what happens:

[image]

Essentially, the workbook becomes corrupted, duplicates the sheets, and deletes all the buttons you could have drawn and associated with macros on any of them.

Debugging the code, I have found the bug, but I don't quite understand its cause.

It seems that **the list that is added to the dropdown is too big**, and that's why excel explodes when reopening (if I don't launch the macro, everything opens smoothly). I have tried to modify the code as follows (adding a **maximum of 21 values** for the dropdown), and doing so I have no problem. Even so, I had understood that the maximum number of values that can be added to a dropdown is around 200 and some...

```
Sub consultaAccess_v4_1()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim datos As Object
    Dim consultaSQL As String
    Dim conexion As String
    Dim cont As Long
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim NombresTablas() As String
    
    Sheets("Indice").Select
    Range("C10").Clear
    
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\0205406\Desktop\Base_Datos(EN PROCESO).accdb"
        
    cn.Open conexion

    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
    i = 0
    a = 0
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If rs.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value Like "MSys*" Then
            rs.MoveNext
        ElseIf rs.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value Like "~*" Then
            rs.MoveNext
        Else
            ReDim Preserve NombresTablas(i)
            NombresTablas(i) = rs.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value
            rs.MoveNext
            i = i + 1
            a = a + 1
            If a = 21 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop

    With Worksheets("Indice").Range("C10").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(NombresTablas, ",")
    End With
    
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Dim t As Range
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, 5), Cells(10, 5))
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    With btn
        .OnAction = "consultaAccess_v4_2"
        .Caption = "Continuar"
        .Name = "Continuar"
    End With
        
    Range("C10").Select
    MsgBox "Seleccione una tabla del desplegable y pulsa 'Continuar'"
End Sub
```

Any idea how to fix this problem? I've been thinking about it for days and nothing.

Comment: `Formula1:=Join(NombresTablas, ",")` After this line can you put this line and tell me what does it give? `Msgbox Len(Join(NombresTablas, ","))`

Comment: Uhm it gives 241. How can it be? There are not that many entrys on NombresTablas (they shouldn't, there are a total of 45 tables)

Comment: Thats 241 characters and not values. Can you `debug.Print Join(NombresTablas, ",")` and check what does it contain?

Comment: It may be the  limitation of 255 characters for string making the list...

Comment: Oh, I see. The result of the debug is the name of all the tables, separated by commas:

Comment: AUX_ANSI,CND1,Dext_ANSI3610,Dext_DIN1755,Dext_DIN2440,Dext_DIN2441,Dext_DIN2445,Dext_DIN2448,DN_ANSI3610,DN_DIN1755,DN_DIN2440,DN_DIN2441,DN_DIN2445,DN_DIN2448,EQUIPOS,EQUIPOS_ESQUEMA,ESPESORES_ANSI,ESPESORES_DIN2445,ESPESORES_DIN2448,GRUPOS

Comment: Why using Excel? Why so many tables with similar names? What is this data? I suspect a non-normalized data structure is at root of issue.

Comment: Hmm, I do not see anything wrong with the string. It is also 241 characters. It should work.

Comment: Should we understand that when the number of characters is 241, do you still have problems you describe?  If not and the problem is strictly connected to the 255 characters (including separator) limitation, you can overpass the problem dropping the array content somewhere on a sheet, name the resulted range and use the named range instead of the string list. The limitation in such a case is 32,767 items...

Comment: I've tried that already, and with that solution the macro works fine. However, I'm kinda curious about the actual problem, it has no sense at all... However, thanks for the thought

Comment: Did you answer referring to my comment? If yes, it should be good to tag the one you try addressing. Otherwise, we are not notified about your comment. In such a case, I did not understand if the 241 characters string works. If yes, it is obviously the known limitation of 255 characters. If not, I do not know what of your string creates the problem...

Comment: @FaneDuru Sorry for not tagging, I'm new here. I've tried to write all the elements from `NombresTablas` onto an auxiliary sheet, and then create a dropdown list from that auxiliary sheet (not directly from the variable on the macro). With this solution, the program works fine, but is not the perfect solution for me, as I would like to not have an  auxiliary sheet.

Comment: I am afraid  nothing else can be done, since Excel has a limitation of maximum 255 characters for the list string...

Comment: Can confirm that  you get this storage error when the formula gets too long. If you don't want to add a (hidden) sheet, maybe placing a combobox can be an alternative

Comment: @FunThomas I'll use the hidden sheet method, I think is the easiest way to solve my problem right now. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @FaneDuru, maybe write an answer with your solution.

Comment: @June7: Not sure I understand what you mean... Are you referring to solution which he already said it uses and it works?

Comment: @FaneDuru, well, yes, the suggestion you made in your first comment. Oh, now I see OP was already aware of that approach. Could still put all this in answer, including  why the string would fail.

Comment: @June7: Since OP said it used this approach, no meaning to post it. If you need it, I can do it if you place a question asking for it and tag me...

Comment: @FaneDuru, I don't need, just thinking it would be a closure for this question.

Comment: @June7: It should only be strange to post an answer containing a solution which is confirmed that the OP uses it... It is not complicated a all. It is nothing special in this approach... To drop an array content in a range is easy, to name the obtained range the same and placing the named range instead of the list it is also something simple.